# How can I add a link on a MediaWiki message page?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

At our company, we have an internal wiki, the access to which is restricted to a specific group. If someone from outside that group attempts access, they will be diverted to the special MediaWiki message page: **MediaWiki:Badaccess-groups**.

I have changed the **MediaWiki:Badaccess-groups** page to contain specific help text. I want to add a link to a wiki page that explains more information. Here's the problem: when I add that link it displays it correctly for me. But for other users it displays as if I'm using <nowiki> tags; literally: **[[link]]**.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just simply link it using html sending them to the page. It's not really the built in way but, it works.

[More Info on Linking in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: Sorry, I can no longer verify this solution as I have long since moved on from that project.

Comment: Well I suggest at least upvoting or accepting an answer then. The question gets bumped periodically, and lets people know that it is an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try using the hyperlink button to make the link? Or, make an external link  that just goes to the Wiki page you're trying to link to.

Comment: if I press the link button I get the standard formatting: **[[link]]**. *I* see it as a link - other users do not (they see **[[link]]**). I'll clarify the question.